# How to enhance thermogram image in grayscale?

Tags: image-processing, highpass-filter, image-restoration, gaussian-kernel

I'm trying to do some image processing to improve the image below but I'm having some trouble. I already tried to do histogram equalization followed by laplace sharpening, I tried to implement a buttersworth high pass filter but the image became all black. Do you have any suggestions on what techniques to use ti improve this image?

[image]

Comment: It's a bit hard to know what "improve" means if you don't tell us what you consider a metric for "improvement"! Also, you'll want to describe the source of the image, too: it looks to me like there was some sensor with a lower resolution (you see the blocks especially at the black-dark gray transitions), but there is also higher-frequency image content. Noise seems to be almost exclusively very high frequency, but not purely additive? We'll need more information on what signal processing steps led to this image, alongside with what you want the image to show.

Comment: But I'll stress that it's important first to understand what your metric for improvement is: if you ask me, this seems to be a physical measurement, and we can't just change values to make it look prettier, we have to retain the meaning of the image *for your specific use case*. Without knowing what is important, we can't do anything.

Comment: improvement would be better contrast, less noise and more defined contours

Comment: so you don't care about the actual values?